# Is there a way to sort lists that correspond with each other?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a function(w) that returns words in a text and their frequencies. I need to write another function(W,F,N) with W being the words in the text, F being their frequencies, and N being how many I want returned. I'm thinking the best way to do this would be to sort W and F in function(W,F,N) in descending order together. Is this possible? Would I need to create my own function to do that? I haven't much experience with sorting but I was thinking maybe after they are sorted do

```
def function(W,F,N):
    .......
    finalList = sortedList[:N]:
    return finalList
```

This is one is homework so I really need explanation so I can understand how to go about this.

Comment: what should function(w,f,n) return? w, f and n are arguments to the function , what is the return value?   Make it clear what types are w, f and n and the return type of your function.

Comment: function(w,f,n) would return the sorted list n amount of times, which I called finalList. I tried to edit it to look like code but didn't happen. And thanks for that other question Daniel, I was looking for one like mine.

Comment: You should first work on giving your functions and parameters descriptive names. Names such as `W`, `F` are not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Zip, sort, unzip:

```
W = ["wolverine", "cat", "dog"]
F = [3, 2, 1]

f, w = zip(*sorted(zip(F, W)))
```

`w` is now the list of words sorted in frequency order.